# Lighthouse audit says content not sized correctly for viewport, despite body width being 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport, lighthouse

I have set the body css of my html page to 100% and with no margins or padding, but it still does not pass the following [Google Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/content-sized-correctly-for-viewport) audit "Content Sized Correctly for Viewport".

> The audit passes if window.innerWidth === window.outerWidth

It says the viewport size is 422px whereas the window size is 412px, so this means the window is 10px wider than wanted.

When I inspect the body element, it is showing as being 412px wide.

I would like to pass this audit, any ideas of what is causing this?

Comment: I have this exact same error (exact pixel dimensions) after running lighthouse. Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't know of a general solution but here is what I would suggest:
1. Make sure the contents of body do not exceed the width of body (including margin, border etc.). Also try messing with the position css property of the body and child elements. Also consider overflow property.
2. If you can't solve it with #1, a possible brutal fix would be to add a small script forcing innerWidth to equal outerWidth, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385768/how-do-you-resize-a-browser-window-so-that-the-inner-width-is-a-specific-value although this is not a good solution even if it works. Good luck.

Comment: In my case, the problem was testing in a monitor which is not the primary one. After I moved the Chrome window under test to the primary monitor, the error gone.

Answer (score 27):

When you reveal the DevTools panel, it usually appears next to the main application page, which messes with the viewport size. I solved the problem by:

- maximizing the browser window
- docking the DevTools panel below the page

Comment: The problem is stupid, but this is the right answer for me... docking the DevTool from Chrome on bottom solved the problem.

Comment: completely correct! im using flex so it shouldnt have been an issue, and it wasn't. thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you have an "*orphan*" `row` Lighthouse fires that error. You need to check where you are using that `row` and wrap it in a class `container-fluid` like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

add this to your css:

```css
html{overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this error when adding my own class to container div that only added some top padding:

```
<div class="container content">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Moving my custom class outside made the audit message go away.

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error while working with Nuxt Js (with Bootstrap) project.

It was due to div tags not closed properly. Normally, you encounter this error when the div hierarchy is not properly maintained, *even if you have properly declared viewport meta tag.*

For example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, if you declare class "row" without defining "container" or "container-fluid", the site content doesn't render with proper margins & paddings needed to fit the content on mobile device; which is the reason why this audit fails on Google Lighthouse.

Let me know, if this resolves your issue.

Comment: That just depends on what css you have in row, and you're using bootstrap css.

Answer (score 0):

Before running the audit test, set the zoom of the browser to 100%. At 100% zoom I passed the audit. For smaller or greater that 100% zoom I got the "Content is not sized correctly for viewport" message - for the desktop audit. Mobile audit was always ok.

Answer (score 0):

This setting **is** affected by the chrome in some browsers. Notably, **Vivaldi**'s "Panel" on the left side (by default) alters the measurement Lighthouse is using to compare `window.innerWidth === window.outerWidth`. You'll need to turn this off to make it work.

To turn this off in Vivaldi, click the main Vivaldi menu in the upper left corner, select "View", then "Show Panel" to toggle it. Alternatively, hit the `F4` key.

Rerun your Lighthouse audit, expand the "Passed Audits" and you should see "Content is size correctly for the viewport".

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and also had this message. After a while I found out that this was because the bootstrap style sheet was not included. I'm using .net MVC with Razor and had to add the following line in my layout.cshtml:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
```