# Google Lighthouse Audit - Content Not Sized Properly For The Viewport

Tags: html, css, progressive-web-apps, viewport, lighthouse

When running a Lighthouse Audit, I've managed to pass all points, but I keep getting an error on the...

*Content is sized correctly for the viewport*

Lighthouse says that the audit passes if window.innerWidth === window.outerWidth

If I log these to the console, they are identical, but I'm still getting the issue and can't seem to fix it. Here's what I've tried so far to resolve it...

Maximising browser window
Docking dev tools panel below / off the page
Wrapped 'orphan' row divs in container-fluid class
Added html {overflow-x: hidden;} to CSS

All the above suggestions were from - [Lighthouse audit says content not sized correctly for viewport, despite body width being 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307689/lighthouse-audit-says-content-not-sized-correctly-for-viewport-despite-body-wid)

I've removed all images from the page to ensure these aren't causing any problems. I've also checked it on most devices to make sure there's no issues.

The meta tag I have in place currently is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Again, logging the widths to the console shows no difference at all so I'm unsure if this is Google failing, or if there's something I'm missing. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Please share the url or the repository, so we can look for ourselves.

Comment: @JoostS I have the same issue, currently live at offseasonscouting.web.app (I don't have a repository set up for it at the moment)

Comment: Is this happening when auditing desktop and mobile, or just one?

Comment: I see nothting at that URL

Comment: It should just be a Firebase setup confirmation, it's intentionally not much but it shouldn't be nothing, and it still fails that mobile audit.

Comment: Same issue. Only occurs when auditing `Device > Mobile`.

Comment: Okay, I've looked around and I think it's a Lighthouse/Chrome bug. I haven't yet found a website that passes this audit in mobile - not even Google's own PWA-compatible pages. Even text-only websites where the lack of CSS or JS means there's no reason for anything to be funny. I'll keep looking, but I think this is a bug.

Comment: @EthanChapman I agree, I stripped my entire page from every element (header, body, footer). Body width is equal to viewport but error message is still there.

Comment: I've now opened this as a bug in the Chromium tracker (#1013455)

Comment: So it seems this bug is fixed in Chrome 78?

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out? December 2022 and I am getting this error even though my site does, indeed, have a viewport tag.