# Content is not sized correctly for the viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, lighthouse

I am deploying my webiste to production and running the Lighthouse audit. The audit is throwing an error when running the audit. It is tell me that the "The viewport size of 373px does not match the window size of 360px". I have validated my HTML and CSS but have not found the specific error. I am not sure if it is in the .style.width of my side nav bars.

[image: Dev Tools Lighthouse Error]

Javascript:

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "150px";
  }
  
  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }

  function openNav2() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav2").style.width = "150px";
  }
  
  function closeNav2() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav2").style.width = "0";
  }

  function openNav3() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav3").style.width = "150px";
  }
  
  function closeNav3() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav3").style.width = "0";
  }
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
.row {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  /* Create three equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
    flex: 33.33%;
    padding: 5px;
  }
 
.imgHoover:hover {
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }

.imgHoover {  
      padding: 10px 16px;
      margin: 10px 0;
      /*box-shadow: 2px 2px grey;*/
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fafafa;
      /*border: 5px solid #fab95b;*/

  }

#form1 {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    background: #fff;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
  }

#form2 {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    background: #fff;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  /* card center */

.card {
    margin: 0 auto; /* Added */
    float: none; /* Added */
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* Added */
    /*box-shadow: 5px 5px grey*/
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

  /* side-nav */

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  }
  
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: #818181;
  }
  
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
  }

html{overflow-x: hidden;}
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

        <!-- ios support -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/logo/icon-96x96.png">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar" content="#292927">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#292927">
        <title>Home-Online Supplements</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #b8dff0;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="images/logo/logo.png" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-top">
                    NextGen-Fitness</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="formButton">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Categories
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Protein</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Vitamins</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Preworkout</a></li>
                        
                        
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html" tabindex="-1" >Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a class="nav-link text-left" href="#" id="userRegistered" style="color:black;" ></a>
               <!-- <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form> -->
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </nav>

        <div class="center-block">    
                <form id="form1">
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" id="fname">
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname">
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email">
                    <br><br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btnUser" onclick="funcUser()">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>


        <!--Side Navbar #1 -->

        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-6 col-md-12 text-lg-rights text-center">
                <img src="images/fatburner-logo2.png" alt class="img-fluid" style="width:100%">           
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="img-area">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/fatburner-1.png" alt="fatBurner" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="img-area">
                    <div class="row">
                        
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/fatburner-2.png" alt="fatBurner" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="img-area">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/fatburner-3.png" alt="fatBurner" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="img-area">
                    <div class="row">
                       
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/fatburner-4.png" alt="fatBurner" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
            
        </div>

        <!--Side Navbar #2 -->

        <div id="mySidenav2" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav2()">&times;</a>
            <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-6 col-md-12 text-lg-rights text-center">
                <img src="images/preworkout-logo.png" alt class="img-fluid" style="width:100%">           
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="img-area">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/preworkout-1.png" alt="fatBurner" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="img-area">
                    <div class="row">
                        
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/preworkout-2.png" alt="fatBurner" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="img-area">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/preworkout-3.png" alt="fatBurner" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="img-area">
                    <div class="row">
                       
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/preworkout-4.png" alt="fatBurner" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
            
        </div>

        <!--Side Navbar #3 -->

        <div id="mySidenav3" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav3()">&times;</a>
            <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-6 col-md-12 text-lg-rights text-center">
                <img src="images/protein-logo.png" alt class="img-fluid" style="width:100%">           
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="img-area">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/protein-1.png" alt="fatBurner" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="img-area">
                    <div class="row">
                        
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/protein-2.png" alt="fatBurner" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="img-area">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/protein-3.png" alt="fatBurner" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="img-area">
                    <div class="row">
                       
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/protein-4.png" alt="fatBurner" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
            
        </div>

        <!--<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>-->

        <div class="bg-light">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row align-items-center no-gutter">
                        <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                            <div class="py-5 py-lg-0">
                                   
                                    
                                    <a class="btn btn-ligth" style="background-color: #fab95b;" href="products.html">Browse all Products</a> 
                                    <!--<a class="btn btn-light" style="background-color: #fab95b;">Are you a Store Owner?</a>-->

                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-6 col-md-12 text-lg-rights text-center">
                            <img src="images/gym-page.jpg" alt class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
        </div>

            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="img-area">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/fatburner-logo2.png" alt="fatBurner" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#!" onclick="openNav()">Fatburner</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/preworkout-logo.png" alt="preWorkout" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#!" onclick="openNav2()">Preworkout</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <img src="images/protein-logo2.png" alt="protein" style="width:100%" class="imgHoover">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#!" onclick="openNav3()">Protein</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    


                    

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-6 col-md-12 text-lg-rights text-center">
                            <img src="images/supplement-frontpage.jpg" alt class="img-fluid" style="width:100%">
                           
            </div>
            <br>
                <div class="container">
                    <p class="text-black-50 mb-4 lead">
                                        
                                        " Hand-picked ingredients and expertly crafted products, 
                                            designed for the modern athletes and trainers."
                    </p>

                </div>
            <br>
            <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-6 col-md-12 text-lg-rights text-center">
                        <img src="images/protein-frontpage.png" alt class="img-fluid" style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="container">
                    <p class="text-black-50 mb-4 lead">
                                        
                                    Benefits Of Protein Supplementation<br>
                                    1.Fast digesting and more easily absorbed than other protein sources<br>
                                    2.Increased muscle mass, especially when taken post-workout<br>
                                    3.Improved appetite control, and greater feelings of fullness when dieting<br>
                                        
                    </p>
           </div>
         <div class="footer">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row align-items-center no-gutters border-top py-2">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                        <span> 2021 NextGen. All Rights Reserved</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                        <nav class="nav justify-content-center justify-content-md-end">
                            <a class="nav-link active pl-0" href="#!">Privacy</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#!">Terms</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#!">Feedback</a>
                        
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your browser zoom is at 100% and make sure DevTools is undocked into a separate window. Those are the first two things to try as in principle the HTML and CSS looks ok (it is impossible to tell as even if I copy it to a fiddle I don't have access to your images to see if they impact the layout in some way).

Comment: Thanks, do you know what the dimensions for a mobile page should be? Should it be no more than 360px?

Comment: A mobile page can be as large as you want it to be, it depends entirely on your site content. Some people use their "mobile layout" all the way to landscape on tablet (1024px for example), others have 2 break points for small mobile screens (<360px) and large mobile screens (<480px). Sorry I can't really give you a better answer than that as mobile screens come in hundreds of different widths. Did you check the two items I mentioned?

Comment: Yeah I did those didn’t work, I will resize all images down smaller.

Comment: @PythonCoder1981  Any update here?  What I'm seeing is if I use horizontal flexbox on desktop menu, I always get this error.  If I go old skool CSS box model, no Lighthouse fail. if I hide flexbox desktop menu with `display:none;` will work, but only with `display:inherit;` on the return.

Answer (score 1):

You could try docking the devtools at the bottom, or in a different window, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51371592/3385948). Sadly, this is still an issue in 2021.

[image: Chrome devtools dock at bottom or in new window]