# Phaser PWA Scaling Issue on Mobile

Tags: progressive-web-apps, phaser-framework

I created a PWA with Phaser 2, following [this tutorial](https://phaser.io/news/2018/10/progressive-web-apps-tutorial) (this one is made with Phaser 3).

I face a problem with how the game scales on mobile. In my game I use these *Phaser 2* methods for scaling:

```
game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
```

When I click the localhost link in my mobile, the game appears way too big, I have to scroll down to see it. When I 'download' it to act like an app, it gets shaky at first, scaling up and down until it settles to the correct size. The game dimensions are 1280x720 and looked very nice before I converted it to a PWA, both on web and on mobile.

I did an audit for a PWA in Chrome's dev tools and it showed this notification:
The viewport size is 1280px, whereas the window size is 412px.

I tried solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307689/lighthouse-audit-says-content-not-sized-correctly-for-viewport-despite-body-wid) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385768/how-do-you-resize-a-browser-window-so-that-the-inner-width-is-a-specific-value) but that did not help. It must be something else.

Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is something I usually do for Phaser 3, but even though you're using Phaser 2 you could try resizing the `canvas` outside of Phaser 2's functionality.

From Emanuele Feronato's [How to scale your HTML5 games if your framework does not feature a scale manager – or if you do not use any framework](https://www.emanueleferonato.com/2018/02/16/how-to-scale-your-html5-games-if-your-framework-does-not-feature-a-scale-manager-or-if-you-do-not-use-any-framework/):

```
/**
 * From https://www.emanueleferonato.com/2018/02/16/how-to-scale-your-html5-games-if-your-framework-does-not-feature-a-scale-manager-or-if-you-do-not-use-any-framework/
 */
function resize() {
    const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight;
    const wratio = width / height;
    const ratio = Number(gameConfig.width) / Number(gameConfig.height);
    if (wratio < ratio) {
        canvas.style.width = width + "px";
        canvas.style.height = (width / ratio) + "px";
    } else {
        canvas.style.width = (height * ratio) + "px";
        canvas.style.height = height + "px";
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
    // setup your game here
    resize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", resize, false);
}
```