# how can we set the size of InnerWidth using an input in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making a fluid responsive font-size calculator where I define the min and max range of font size through an input. Now I want to set the specific size of innerWidth where I can set up a limit of width size through input.

I was able to change the width of body now I want to change the innerWidth through input.

```js
const { StrictMode, useEffect, useState } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

function InputSize() {
  const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState(6);
  const [min, setMin] = useState(24);
  const [max, setMax] = useState(45);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    function adjustFontSize() {

      const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
      const newFontSize = Math.max(Number(min), Math.min(Number(max), Math.floor(windowWidth / 100) + Number(min)));
      document.body.style.fontSize = `${newFontSize}px`;
      setFontSize(newFontSize);
    }
    adjustFontSize();

    window.addEventListener('resize', adjustFontSize);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', adjustFontSize);
  }, [min, max]);

  function newWidthSize(e) {
    const newWidth = e.target.value
    console.log(newWidth);
    setWidth(newWidth)
    document.body.style.width = `${newWidth}px`;
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <input type="number" label="From" value={min} onChange={(e) => setMin(e.target.value)} />
      <input type="number" label="to" value={max} onChange={(e) => setMax(e.target.value)} />
      <input type="number" label="to" value={width} onChange={newWidthSize} />
      <p>{width}</p>
      <p style={{ fontSize: `${fontSize}px` }}>Sample text with dynamic font size.</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return <InputSize />
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you resize a browser window so that the inner width is a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385768/how-do-you-resize-a-browser-window-so-that-the-inner-width-is-a-specific-value)

Comment: Note: It's not possible to resize a window or tab that wasn't created by `window.open()`. It's also not possible to resize when the window has multiple tabs. ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo))

Comment: https://websemantics.uk/tools/responsive-font-calculator/

Comment: Reference website link.